# Методика разработки классов PHP

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста книги или статьи по методике разработки классов. Задача:

- Создать WEB портал с ограничением прав доступа к сайту
- Портал будет взаимодействовать с базой данных (куда без этого)
- Портал должен иметь функционал WebSocket
- На сайте можно импортировать\экспортировать данные в\из базу данных
- Логирование перемещения пользователей по сайту.

Это основные задачи, вероятно я много еще и не учел т.к. опыта мало. Хотелось бы найти информацию в которой бы ясно, четко и по шагам были изложены действия по созданию WEB порталов.

Comment: Судя по описанию и если у вас нет необходимости писать все самостоятельно, вам сразу в документацию к [Ларавел](https://laravel.com/docs/). Мнение субъективное.

Comment: Есть желание писать самостоятельно.

Comment: Тут много полезной инфы (кроме вебсокетов, это ищи отдельно) https://www.youtube.com/user/TheLukesky1/playlists